# Querying/sending large amount of push notifications, how to test speed before deployment?

Tags: parse-platform

I am working on migrating my parse.com app to Heroku, with the DB hosted on mLab.
I have already migrated my parse.com data to mLab. 
I have a sandbox Parse Server running on Heroku pointed at a sandbox DB on mLab.

The main function of my app involves sending 1000+ time sensitive push notifications to instances of my (iOS only) app. The notifications need to be delivered within a few seconds to be very useful.

The pushes are generated by my server PC at home which sends push queries to the parse server.

What is the best way to test the speed of querying/pushing to a large amount of (iOS) installations with this setup?

Is there a way to create dummy PFInstallation objects to test with, or some other method?

Comment: You ahould read more about apple push notifications (apn), technically you dont send them, you tell apple to send them to these devices with this token and id...your server communicates just with apple...

Comment: But I need to be able to test how this setup will compare with the speed of parse.com, which was very fast when querying/sending a large number of notifications. See this link for why I am worried: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1292

Comment: maybe sending Pushes with channels might be faster wit parse-server...

Answer (score 0):

push notifications performance is not something that you can control on. When you send a push to one or more iOS devices you send it to APNS (apple push notifications server) and then APNS will send the notification to the devices. Usually APNS performance are pretty good and work very fast but you cannot say that its **real time** because sometimes you may experience some delay when you will try to send the notification. 
Also push notification works in **fire-and-forget** means that you cannot really know if the notification arrived to your device.

Comment: I probably didn't word my question very well... I do understand that push notifications are fire-and-forget and that the performance can't be controlled. **My question is specific to Parse and how to go about testing the speed of generating the notifications through my own Parse server, without actually sending notifications to my active users**.